Expo AuthSession not closing when receiving redirectUri on Android
I am developing an ecommerce app for a client and I have had trouble with the authentication process for the application, but only on the Android platform as everything already works as expected on iOS. Let me explain the problem in detail and how I have set everything up.
I am using Expo's AuthSession for handling the authentication process through the browser. In short, AuthSession has a redirectUri parameter that when detected in the browser, the browser is dismissed and the auth process gets a type of 'success', which then also returns the redirect uri with the parameters I need for the next steps of authentication.
I have managed to figure out that the problem seems to be Android handling the browser process differently as it opens a "Custom Chrome Tab", which closes the application and stops it expo-auth-session and/or expo-web-browser from redirecting to the application. I have gone up and down all the documentation and even going as far as getting into working with Intent for Android, but even that does not seem to solve the issue. At this point, I suspect it is either a problem with the library or just not possible in this way. I am open to trying out all and any tips anyone might have on this.
Below is my code example. All the code is involved in authorization only, so all parts are relevant. Again, everything works perfectly on iOS; Android is the only platform that is giving me trouble for this.
export default function Login() {

    const [result, setResult] = useState<AuthSessionResult | null>(null)
    const [authRequest, setAuthRequest] = useState<AuthRequest | null>(null)

    const storeID = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_STORE_ID
    const clientID = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID

    const authorizationRequestUrl = new URL(`https://shopify.com/${storeID}/auth/oauth/authorize`)

    const redirect_uri = `shop.${storeID}.app://authorize`

    const handleAuthSession = async () => {
        try {
            if (authRequest) {
                console.log('Making Auth Request')
                let response = await authRequest.promptAsync({
                    authorizationEndpoint: authorizationRequestUrl.toString()
                })
                setResult(response)
            } else {
                console.log("Could not make request");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const getAuthSessionInfo= async () => {
            const verifier = await generateCodeVerifier()
            const challenge = await generateCodeChallenge(verifier!)
            const state = await generateState()
            const nonce = await generateNonce(10)

            setAuthRequest( new AuthRequest({
                redirectUri: redirect_uri,
                state: state,
                responseType: 'code',
                clientId: clientID!,
                codeChallenge: challenge,
                codeChallengeMethod: CodeChallengeMethod.S256,
                scopes: [
                    'openid',
                    'email',
                    'https://api.customers.com/auth/customer.graphql'
                ],
                extraParams: {
                    nonce: nonce
                }
            }))
        }
        
        getAuthSessionInfo()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(result)
    }, [result])

    return (
        <ThemedView>
            <Suspense fallback={<ActivityIndicator/>}>
                <Pressable onPress={() => router.canGoBack() && router.back()}><ThemedText>Go Back</ThemedText></Pressable>
                <Pressable 
                    onPress={handleAuthSession}
                    >
                    <ThemedText>Sign In</ThemedText>
                </Pressable>
                <Pressable onPress={() => router.push('/(drawer)/')}><ThemedText>Navigate to Home</ThemedText></Pressable>
                <ThemedText>{JSON.stringify(result) ?? ''}</ThemedText>
            </Suspense>
        </ThemedView>
    )
}

I have tried switching to using expo-web-browser's WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync() function, but everything just worked the exact same way things work right now.
I have also tried changing intent on Android, but that does not seem to work at all.
I have used another devices to see if the results change in any way, and the app seems to react in the same exact way in all devices.

I had the same problem, what fixed it for me is going to the androidManifest.xml file and in the intent-filter section adding:
<data android: scheme="YOUR_SCHEME" android: path="YOUR_CUSTOM_PATH" /.>

